# How to make this array .to_json (Ruby)? It's acting odd in my program, but works fine in irb

Tags: ruby, json, sockets

I can convert to json in irb, but not in program.  For instance, in irb:

```
require 'json'
deck = %w(2 4 6 5 K)
=> ["2", "4", "6", "5", "K"]
deck_json = deck.to_json
=> "[\"2\",\"4\",\"6\",\"5\",\"K\"]"  # <= Great, this works, however....
```

When I actually try do do this in my program in Ruby, it works differently.  I inserted a puts the player's cards with and without json.  I can also set a `var = somecode.to_json`, but both puts yield the same thing.  No to_json, just the card hand.

```
game_name.player.each do |player|
  puts "Here's the player's cards: #{player.fish_hand.player_cards}"
  puts "And here's the hand in json: #{player.fish_hand.player_cards.to_json}"

  #you can IGNORE this part below:

  #player.socket_number.puts(player.fish_hand.player_cards.to_json)
  #puts "Here's the json data? #{player.fish_hand.player_cards.to_json}"
  #cards_for_client = player.fish_hand.player_cards.to_json
  #player.socket_number.puts(cards_for_client)    #JSON DATA!
  #puts "Card for client json data: #{cards_for_client}"
end
```

I need to get it to json so that I can send an array across a server to a client.  How can I get this into json?

Comment: It is not jason, it is json.

Comment: That's a typo I wrote here.  It's not in my code.

Comment: I edited it for you =).  If it was in my code terminal would have yelled at me.  The code RUNS, it just doesn't output the array in json.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Given your first example, both `puts` statements **should** print the same thing. Try doing both `puts` in irb with your first example and you should see that.

irb is printing the string representation of the output of the #to_json method, so you get the escaped quotes.  `puts` is getting the string representation of the json structure, in this case, an array of strings, and displaying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_json` is working. The contrast you see is not due to irb versus script, but is `p` versus `puts` or inspection `"#{}"`. `p` applies `inspect` on the object and displays it in a form close (not necessarily the same always) to how it is expressed in the code. That is what you see in irb. On the other hand, `puts` or `"#{}"` applies `to_s` to the object, making it more like an ordinary text that you would see in a document. When you want to see what object you have, use `p`.

Comment: Thanks sawa!  That did it.  I'll be running that server in no time =)